# Create a function to bind rows in R

Tags: r, function, bind

I created a function in R to take some columns of a data frame, becouse they are cases of a sample and not variables:

> df<- function(x) {
> ex <- data %>% select(1,date=1+x,value=301+x,602)
> (ex)
> }

The idea was to merge them all with something like this

> data<- bind_rows(
> df(1:20))

So i would bind all rows from the function from x=1 to x=20.
But looks like i cant do that, and i have to do something like this instead:

> data<- bind_rows(
> df(1),df(2),df(3).....)

I thik i might need another function but i am not sure about how to solve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve in a little more detail? How does the dataframe 'data' look like? What kind of iinput is x? Some numeric value?

Comment: It would be a great help to those wishing to help if you could create a minimal reproducible example, have a look at [mre]

Comment: Thank you for your commnts, Alan solved my issue but i will read about how to be clear using a minimal reproducible example, next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complex than it needs to be. Suppose my data looks like this:

```r
data <- iris[11:15, ]
data
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
#> 13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
```

Now imagine I want to take column 2, 3 and 4 as observations instead of variables. Then I can just select the columns like this:

```
data[2:4]
#>    Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 11         3.7          1.5         0.2
#> 12         3.4          1.6         0.2
#> 13         3.0          1.4         0.1
#> 14         3.0          1.1         0.1
#> 15         4.0          1.2         0.2
```

And to transpose them I can just use `t()` and convert the resulting matrix to a data frame.

```
as.data.frame(t(data[2:4]))
#>               11  12  13  14  15
#> Sepal.Width  3.7 3.4 3.0 3.0 4.0
#> Petal.Length 1.5 1.6 1.4 1.1 1.2
#> Petal.Width  0.2 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.2
```

For completeness, I can set the row and column names to whatever I want:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(data[2:4]), row.names = 1:3), paste0("var", 1:5))
#>   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
#> 1  3.7  3.4  3.0  3.0  4.0
#> 2  1.5  1.6  1.4  1.1  1.2
#> 3  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.2
```

So in your case, the function might look something like this:

```
df <- function(x) {
  as.data.frame(t(data[x]), row.names = seq_along(x)) %>%
  setNames(paste0("var", seq(nrow(data))))
}
```

And you would get a nice data frame by just doing `df(1:20)`
}

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Alan, that was an amazing answer. Thaank you for your time, you saved me a lot of issues.